# Odd output from a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sdl

I'm using a for loop to iterate through some arrays I've created representing regions that the mouse can hover over. Then when the loop confirms the mouse is in a region it saves the iteration variable to a public variable that is used later in the main function to highlight the region the mouse is over. The problem is that the for loop is not giving the right value for the first iteration through.

```
{
//mouse offsets
int x = 0, y = 0;
//if mouse moves
if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
{
    //get the mouse co-ords
    x = event.motion.x;
    y = event.motion.y;

    for (int grid = 0; grid <= sizeof(grid_region); grid++)
    {

        if ((x > grid_region[grid].x) && (x < grid_region[grid].x + GRID_WIDTH) && (y > grid_region[grid].y) && (y < grid_region[grid].y + GRID_HEIGHT))
        {
            //set highlight region
            highlight = grid;
        }
    }
}
```

}

grid_region is is made via "int grid_region[9];" and the strange part is that when I later do a print statement to see what "highlight" is when it's in grid_region[0] is prints 72. How is it possible that the iteration variable becomes 72 at any point in the loop??? Any help here? I later use highlight to apply a sprite in the grid_region and it's being applied incorrectly so this is a problem.

Comment: One problem I see is the test in the outer for loop, it should probably be `grid < sizeof(grid_region)`

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(grid_region)` is the size *in multiples of `char`*, not the number of elements.

That is, it is `sizeof(int) * 9`, not nine, and apparently your `int` is 8 `char`s wide since you ended up at 72.

You can loop to `< sizeof(grid_region) / sizeof(grid_region[0])` or, better, step into the 21st century and use `std::vector`, or `std::array` if your compiler is hip enough.

Comment: `std::vector` is so 1998 - `std::array` is the fashionable programmer's choice for statically-sized sequences.

Comment: @Casey I tend to forget about C++0xb since the code I work with daily is ancient. Added a fashion statement to the answer.